# Lua-type Java integration with C++

Tags: java, c++, scripting, mono, integration

So I'm curious:

I've implemented Lua within C++ a few times before, and while it was relatively simple, it still didn't harness the power that I would have liked.

I love how eclipse works, including javadoc locations, etc. and I was wondering if there was a way to integrate Java into a native application (that is cross-platform, of course) to do what Lua does, but with Java.

This means I'd be able to build my own base classes and stuff, etc.

Just an interesting thought! Any insight?

EDIT: Also, what about MonoDevelop? Is it relatively easy to integrate? Is it compiled? Is it cross-platform-able?

Comment: I very much doubt a language designed for a freestanding virtual machine rather than for embedding (as Lua) will do great at embedding. That's not to say it's impossible, but chances are it will be very painful.

Comment: yea I figured. I just love the ease of inheritance that java has.

Comment: Do you want to integrate C++ and Java or Java and Lua?

Comment: C++ and Java, much like how you would integrate C++ and Lua.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As someone mentioned in the comments, hosting Java within a C++ app would be difficult. You'd have to provide an environment for it to run in. It's not outside the realm of posibilities though. For example, the mono project has IKVM with is a .NET implementation of the Java Virtual Machine. This allows Java and .NET code to run together. Look at the sources of IKVM to get a grasp of the magnitude of making such an effort with C++.

There is a similar project called [Junc++ion](http://codemesh.com/products/junction/) but I don't have any experience using it. One of the features they highlight is a shared JVM which forgoes the necessity to have a separate JRE installed on the machine. From the looks of things though, it only supports invoking Java code from C++ not the other way around.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to check it out. I was planning on using Lua for this particular project, but if I can get Java working (well) then I might give it a shot.